# Looking for enterprise web application design inspiration

Tags: web-development, web-applications, websites

I've checked many websites to be inspired about what the look and feel of a serious enterprise web-application should look like. But the whole I saw were designed for being used by single users and not serious corporate users. The designs I saw were mostly happy-colored, and looked like being developed by a small team of eager young passionate developers.

But what I'm looking for, are showcases of serious web apps' designs (e.g. web apps developed by large corporations) that are developed for being used by a large number of corporate uses.

Can you suggest me sources for this kind of inspiration?

Comment: look at the ExtJS examples, http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/ - that's how serious web apps might look like.

Comment: inspiration for what large companies do... go to any governmental office and look at the clerks screen, note the '98 access appearance (or worse, blue screen).. large corporations are not a place to get inspiration from for just about anything other than how to structure a bureaucracy.

Comment: So you don't know any web page that showcases enterprise web app designs?

Comment: Did you look at the ExtJS examples?

Comment: Yes dear Robert. I checked it out. Actually I was looking for sth more than beutiful components as I'm using Telerik's products and in component level, everything is ok. What I'm looking for is inspiration for app layout and items arrangment and application theming for serious corporate scenarios that offer sth more than what is popular currently.

Comment: Telerik has [examples on their website](http://www.telerik.com/support/demos/developer-tools-demos.aspx).  What does "sth" mean?  Are you really trying to say 5th?  Or are you trying to say ***something*** else?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see what corporate look and feel that's been designed by a committee and tweaked over a number of years, I can think of no better example than Microsoft's online version of Outlook.

Failing that, take a look at Salesforce.com or QuickBooks Online.

Use TMN's advice to see these if you don't have access.

These are all example of well-designed, but very boring and to the point interfaces, which is what you seem to be after.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Google image search and enter  "${product} screenshots" where "${product}" is something like "peoplesoft" or "sap financials" or "baan".  Not sure how inspiring they'll be (enterprise-class systems are rarely sexy) but they'll be real-world examples.

Comment: I've do this before but when a web page showcases some, it usually means that there have been some notable points to ponder about that web app. Otherwise I've checked many of web apps that are developed by large corporations before.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I'd use the phrase "serious web apps" to describe the typical enterprise app - most consumer facing apps/sites these days are built to be more scalable than the typical multi-tier "enterprise" app.  Different apps, different challenges.

That being said, an *enterprise* application is usually less focused around messaging/content (etc.) and more focused on the ability to view and/or manipulate *data*.  It's usually the ability to view and manipulate data that good enterprise design allows users to do.

A good example (and possibly a solution for you) in terms of enterprise design is Oracle's "Application Development Framework" (ADF), specifically the "ADF Rich Faces" components.

(There's a version you can freely experiment with here:  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/overview/adfessentials-1719844.html  You might also want to grab a copy of JDeveloper for simple exploration.)

Compare the design of the data-driven components (tables, components designed for data display) versus the design of other JSF libraries like PrimeFaces; while both can be comparable, the ADF Rich Faces libraries are designed with mass data views and manipulations in mind.